# Localization doesn't apply new language to all pages

Tags: c#, localization, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor project, where I am trying to add my first language to my application. I have gotten pretty far, where I can select a language from a multi-selection box and changes the language. My only problem is that it only changes the language in the current .razor file and not in the whole application.

I already set up the .resx files in my `Resources` folder and added it like that:

```
serviceCollection.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

This line of code is in a static function for the type `IServiceCollection`:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddBlazorServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    return serviceCollection;
}
```

and this function is called finally in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var circuitRetentionPeriod = Configuration.GetValue("DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriodInMinutes", 3);

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddCircuitOptions(a => a.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod =                                                     System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(circuitRetentionPeriod))
                .AddHubOptions(hub => hub.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 100 * 128 * 128); // 100 MB

            services.AddScoped<CircuitHandler>((sp) => new CircuitHandlerService(sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CircuitHandlerService>>(), sp.GetRequiredService<CircuitsCounterService>()));
            services.AddSingleton<CircuitsCounterService>();

            services.AddScoped<CorrelationProvider>();

            services.AddApplicationServices();
            services.AddBlazorServices();
            services.AddForeignServices();
        }
```

I also already moved all strings in my application to the .resx files and added it back via the `IStringLocalizer<>`. I translated also every .resx file into another language. Currently it displays the language based on your system-language in your device. Now I would like to control that via a razor-file.

In a razor file, I have a default <select> (default html-element) where I can select between languages. As soon as you click to one option, it fires the following method:

```
    void RequestCultureChange()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedCulture))
            return;

        if (selectedCulture == "de-CH")
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("de-CH");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }
        else if (selectedCulture == "en-US")
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }
    }
```

As I said, this only changes the language in the current .razor file. Do you know what my potential mistake is?

I already did some research but did not find any solution. I also do not want any cookies with this information, since it's planned to save the data to the user profile in a database, in case some information has to be stored permanently to make it work.

Comment: Is this Blazor server or WASM?

Comment: @Axekan Yes Blazor server with the design pattern MVVM

Comment: @Axekan you there?

Comment: I have full localization working in my Blazor server app, but it uses cookies and request localization so I don't know if I can help you if you don't want to make use of those things.

Comment: @Axekan I've now managed to find out how I can set the language to the whole application by doing it in startup.cs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#localization

Now I have the issue that I need to read a value from the Localstorage to know what language the user saved. For that, I need to get a value from a Service directly in Startup.cs. I will create a separate thread for that.

Comment: @Axekan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75937043/how-to-use-a-service-directly-in-startup-cs